# Azure API Connection - how to recover user info

Tags: azure

I need to list sql users that are being used by some azure API Connection. How can I retrive this information? I can view server and database via properties, but the user seens to be hiden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just received an answer from Azure support team confirming that there is no way to recovery this information via azure portal.

What they said it was possible, it is to check Azure SQL Database logs or open sessions (while executing the logic app) to get the user from the session.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Please accept your answer.